# Is Groot still used to monitor nav2 behaviour tree in 2024? (ROS2-Humble)

Tags: ros-humble, nav2

It's my first question here, so if I'm posting the question in the wrong place please notify to me.

The question came to my mind while I was performing some experiments using turtlebot3. My goal was to launch the turtlebot nav2 simulation using `tb3_simulation` from `nav2_bringup` as described in https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#running-the-example and monitor the default behaviour tree running using **Groot**. When it was the moment to connect the Groot monitor I didn't get which port am i supposed to use (I am on ROS2-Humble). Searching on the web I am not finding any satisfactory answer and I'm finding out there is a lot of confusion around. Moreover, I've also found out that there are some posts where it's stated that Groot monitor is dismissed using ROS2.

At this point, I am confused too!

Can someone confirm for me that it is still (in 2024) possible to use Groot (or Groot2) to monitor in real-time the behaviour tree of a nav2 stack, using ROS2-Humble and Nav2 ?